# Access the Graph Api from template .net Core app

Tags: azure, api, graph, .net-core

I have a .net core web app which was built using the built in template for using office365 account for authentication. The app is working perfectly. I have the clientID, client Secret, registered the app in azure, have the correct scopes in the appsettings json etc etc. 
I can log in using my office 365 account.
What I cant do though is access the graph api as the logged in user.

All the examples talk about creating
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
 However none of these examples fit the visual studio template.

How can I access the graph api using the logged in user?

Comment: Basically trying to get this code to work
  GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            
            //var messages = await GetMessages(graphClient);
            var users = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
            ReceiveEmail();
            return View();

Comment: Have you gone through this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview? What is wrong with `GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider)`? Are there any error messages? Please add more details.

Comment: Hi, yes, I've been through the overview and installed the sdks, including graph, graph.core and graph.auth.

The app runs fine and I can log in using my office 365 account. However, still cant pull back any data from the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you need to [Install the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-net-sdk) first.

Then before you could use `GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider)`, you should [Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS).

In this case, you want to access the graph api using the logged in user. So you should choose [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider).

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret) // or .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .Build();

AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);
```

Comment: Thanks, I installed the miscrosft graph .net sdk and inserted the authorization provider suggested but I get an 'authenicationChallendeRequred' error message.

Comment: '
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("***….")
            .WithRedirectUri("https://localhost:44310")
            .WithClientSecret("***...") 
            .Build();
            AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication,scopes);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider); 

            var users = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();'

Comment: @JoeSmith Can you debug it the see which code pulls this error?